# Remove "can be backordered" from product page stock display in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

It doesn't make sense to me to have the '(can be backordered)' text on a Woocommerce product page if the product is in stock as that confuses people because, after all, it's in stock!

I have found code to change the message if it is backordered but not how to remove it if the product is in stock and I have searched on the net for hours.

Can anyone provide me with the code required in the functions.php file or elsewhere to change it globally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Updated**

The following code will remove "(can be backordered)" text from the product availability text, when product is in stock and backorders are allowed (with a customer notification):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'filter_product_availability_text', 10, 2 );
function filter_product_availability_text( $availability, $product ) {

    if( $product->backorders_require_notification() ) {
        $availability = str_replace('(can be backordered)', '', $availability);
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show the text "can be backordered", on products that have inventory quantity equal or less than value set on "Low stock threshold" :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'filter_product_availability_text', 10, 2 );
function filter_product_availability_text( $availability, $product ) {

if( $product->get_stock_quantity () > get_option( 'woocommerce_notify_low_stock_amount' )) {
    $availability = str_replace('(can be backordered)', '', $availability);
 }
 return $availability;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wonder how to make this work in any language you should use `preg_replace` with regular expression instead of `str_replace`.

Like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'filter_product_availability_text', 10, 2 );
function filter_product_availability_text( $availability, $product ) {

if( $product->backorders_require_notification() ) {
    $availability = preg_replace( '/\(.*\)/', '', $availability );
}
return $availability;
```

}

This will remove everything within those two parentheses including the parentheses themselves. Useful especially for people using WPML and other multilingual plugins.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot the translation string. It will be:

```
$availability = str_replace(__( '(can be backordered)', 'woocommerce' ), '', $availability);
```

Answer (score -1):

all you have to do is to go here

woocommerce/includes/wc-formatting-functions.php

and at line 1197

change

if ( $product->backorders_allowed() && $product->backorders_require_notification() ) {
        $display .= ' ' . __( '(can be backordered)', 'woocommerce' );
    }

to

if ( $product->backorders_allowed() && $product->backorders_require_notification() ) {
        $display .= ' ' . __( '', 'woocommerce' );
    }

hope that helps! :)

Comment: You shouldn't be editing plugin files, these changes will get wiped when you update the plugin.